# Read .xlsx File - XSSFWorkBook - POI - Zip error

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am actually trying to convert an .xlsx file to .csv file. I found many ressources on web about how to convert from .xlsx to .csv.

I try this one :

```
private static void convertSelectedSheetInXLXSFileToCSV(File xlsxFile, int sheetIdx) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(xlsxFile);

    // Open the xlsx and get the requested sheet from the workbook
    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInStream);
    XSSFSheet selSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);
```

...

[in color!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOP7J.png)

The code seems to be ok, but I have an exception that I am not able to understand...

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:103)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
at fr.cls.ihs.injector.reader.ConvertXLSXToCSV.convertSelectedSheetInXLXSFileToCSV(ConvertXLSXToCSV.java:21)
at fr.cls.ihs.injector.reader.ConvertXLSXToCSV.convert(ConvertXLSXToCSV.java:64)
at fr.cls.ihs.injector.processing.ConverterProcessing.process(ConverterProcessing.java:46)
at fr.cls.ihs.injector.pool.IhsInjectorRunnable.process(IhsInjectorRunnable.java:64)
at fr.cls.generic.server.processing.AbstractServerProcessing.execute(AbstractServerProcessing.java:58)
at fr.cls.generic.server.runnable.GenericRunnable.run(GenericRunnable.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: too many length or distance symbols
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:220)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:132)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:56)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:100)
```

[in color!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyJsA.png)

To solve it, I tryed to use another XSSFworkbook constructor with String or Zip parameter but is not what I am looking for.

If someone have any idea about how I could solve a part of the error, it could be great :D

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Seems as if the `xlsxFile` is not fully ready. Can it be that it is filled from another thread while this thread tries opening it?

Comment: I solved my problem this morning. Problem was not correlated with POI but with my file management.
I put in argument my File's content instead of the whole file.

Thank you anyway my friend =)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more how you fixed it? I am having the same issue. @mehdmed

Comment: Explain it please - same issue here